# How to unaccept question not accepted?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

[image]

As you can see, it was unaccepted, and then accepted. But it was fresh answer posted today, never accepted before. And it is not a case of wrong order: [answer is still accepted](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/99229/16495). But it seems I only have upvote rep points for it. Not that I really care about that 15 rep, but something strange seems to be happening.

Comment: Looks normal to me

Comment: @Bala now it does. Back then it didn't, but I can believe it's cache. Anyway, something unaccepted before it was accepted is not normal, but oh well, caching ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems that you've got a cached rep breakdown of the moment in time just between the moment where your unaccepted answer and accepted again. The answer was accepted again just around the time you've posted this bug report.

[image: current breakdown]

Comment: Cache would indeed explain why I have seen it accepted. But seeing it unaccepted before it was accepted on the list was strange. Anyway, now I see it normal, so probably cache it is, thank you.